# Set local commit email adress for all subdirectories

Tags: git

For my university, i am required to commit all my work with my university email. How can i set the commit email for my school directory and all subdirectories without changing my global git email as i need that for another projects.
Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+different+email

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `.gitconfig` file in the parent directory that hosts your git repos on disk and store any settings unique to that collection of repositories.

These settings can then be overwritten by the config of the actual repository itself.

You can set any settings that are unique to all the projects in that subfolder, like your name, email, signing keys etc.

[image]